# laravel 4 install failure

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, laravel-4

I have been trying to get laravel installed with no success.
I have been following what seems to be the usual recipe

```
git clone -b develop git://github.com/laravel/laravel.git myapp
cd myapp
curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/installer | php
php composer.phar install
```

When I run it  I always get the following. I tried killing the cache dir updating etc.

Running PHP Version 5.4.6 open-ssl , mcrypt enabled in the cli.

Just don't know what I'm missing. Been giving it a shot for over a week. Saw some talk about network issues. When I manually download the json in the browser, I notice it redirects to a secure https url. Any pointers would be great. I've have never had a problem like this where I have not been able to dig up the answer.

```
# php composer.phar install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies

  [Composer\Downloader\TransportException]
  The "http://packagist.org/p/laravel/framework$de13d7a9bde179aa3dbe63308a250
  911fa2330b3e0ba7510dea52827ec3c2f14.json" file could not be downloaded: fai
  led to open stream: HTTP request failed!
```

Comment: What error(s) are you getting?

Comment: My errors are above, the transport exceptions. It's a composer thing. I can't get composer to install anything. I am getting closer to an answer.

Comment: This, to me, seems very much Composer related and not Laravel related. Have you tried creating a simple `composer.json` file which requires a random library and running `composer install` to see if that works. If it does then we can at least say it might be something related to the Laravel repository but I can confirm it works on my end. There must be some weird connectivity problems. Perhaps try another computer as well. Just try to narrow the problem down.

Comment: http://codinginharmony.blogspot.com/2012/10/forcing-composer-to-use-https.html#comment-form

Comment: I noticed with wget or a browser, I would get an https redirect. It seems that however composer does it is different enough from these other 2 that it creates a firewall problem. The link above solved it by adding a section to my composer.json file. Now it doesn't need to redirect as it is starting at https

Comment: `"repositories": [
    {
         "type": "composer",
         "url": "https://packagist.org"
    },
    { "packagist": false }
]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I noticed with wget or a browser, I would get an https redirect. It seems that however composer does it is different enough from these other 2 that it creates a firewall problem. The link above solved it by adding a section to my composer.json file. Now it doesn't need to redirect as it is starting at https. I am running behind a sonicwall. I am not sure why it would work with a browser and wget, but not composer. It solved it however.

Answer (score 0):

You're cloning the Developer branch from github. This version can be broken in the moment. So you could wait and try it later again (maybe it'll get fixed meanwhile) or you download this [develop.zip](https://github.com/laravel/laravel/archive/develop.zip) which is the official way described in the L4 documentation.

Comment: I cant get composer to download anything. I don't use a proxy. when I do a php composer.phar diag  everything is OK.

Comment: Strange. Maybe an antivirus software is blocking your ports. I've seen this before.

Comment: Also, as far as I know, that ZIP is kept up to date with the latest commits to the repository. It's essentially the same as cloning the repository.

Comment: @Hexodus I am running on a Ubuntu 12.10 vm, so I don't have any antivirus stuff happening there. I am running behind a firewall, but I am not running any kind of proxy services.    @Jason Lewis  While I am still at step one with this, and I don't know what goes where yet, I believe that the contents of the develop.zip does not have the vendor directory with the actual framework code in it. The `php composer.phar install` line is supposed to take care of all that.

Comment: Oh I'm totally lost with linux. Hope you can solve this problem anyways.